# Custom data attribute not working inside <select> tag

Tags: jquery, html, dom

See this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="Template/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" ></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $(".myselect").change(function(){
                alert( $(this).attr('data-spacing') );
            });

        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <select name="type" class="myselect">
        <option data-spacing="001" value="" selected >Select A Camera</option>
        <option data-spacing="002" value="Nicon_D500">Nicon D500</option>
        <option data-spacing="004" value="Nicon_D600">Nicon D600</option>
        <option data-spacing="003" value="Canon_S900">Canon S900</option>
    </select>

    </body>
</html>
```

The `data-custom` attribute is working for anything,
but it's not working for `<select>` and `<option>` tags.

This source code returns "Undefined"
Please help me.

Comment: In this instance $(this) refers to the select element, not the option element.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The data attribute belongs to the option element, but the change handler is registered to the select element so `this` inside the change handler refers to the select element which does not have the `data-*` attribute

You need to find the actual `option` element which was selected(you can use the [:selected-selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)) to do that.

Also use the [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) api to read the value of `data-*`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".myselect").change(function () {
        alert($(this).find('option:selected').data('spacing'));
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8F5eC/)

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
$(this).data('spacing')
```

Comment: Manam Iraniam Agha hadi... ;)

Comment: Salam, khoshhalam, soale shoma ro emtiyaz dadam.